# write string to xml file located in appdata\local

Tags: c#, xml

Im new to c# and i would like to know how to write the string `<Package name="gaffersimulations-fale" active="true"/>` between a specific tag in an xml file located in appdata/local.

what im trying to achieve:

```
<content>
  <Package name="gaffersimulations-fale" active="true"/>
</content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement content = new XElement("content");

            XElement package = new XElement("Package", new object[] {
                new XAttribute("name", "gaffersimulations-fale"),
                new XAttribute("active", "true")
            });
            content.Add(package);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, nothing gets written to file except for "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" at the top

Comment: I'm not writing anything.  You would need to use : content.Save("filename");